# Flask in Docker unable to detect FLASK_ENV

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

I built a flask app and launch it in docker with the Dockerfile as below.

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
WORKDIR /app

CMD export FLASK_ENV=production    
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-u", "app.py" ]
```

In the flask app, I specified some configuration for development & production

```
if os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] == 'production':
    UPLOAD_URL = '/v1/path/to/production/server'
elif os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] == 'development':
    UPLOAD_URL = '/upload'
```

However, launching the script caused an error, where the container cannot detect the FLASK_ENV, even though the command was set in the Dockerfile. Can anyone help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    import config
  File "/app/config.py", line 14, in <module>
    if os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] == 'production':
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'FLASK_ENV'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run the resulting image, [`ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  The `CMD` you describe will be wrapped in `sh -c` and then passed as command-line arguments to the program you name as the `ENTRYPOINT`.

(In your application, try printing out [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).  You should see this contain `["app.py", "/bin/sh", "-c", "export ..."]`.)

If you want to set an environment variable for the image, you need the Dockerfile [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive.  (You cannot for example `RUN export ...`; any variables you set this way will be lost at the end of the `RUN` line.)

```
ENV FLASK_ENV=production    
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace : 
CMD export FLASK_ENV=production

with : 
ENV FLASK_ENV=production

ENV instruction is also useful for providing environment variables to services you wish to containerize.